# Logging into CAM UI is not possible

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-automation-manager

Trying to open the CAM console (https://CAM_IP_address:30000) the url is being redirected to the ICP console (that is normal behavior) 
but if I login as admin I'm getting the ICP Console and not the CAM console.
Looking at the pod status you will notice that cam-iaas pod is in running state.
In the cam-iaas logs the following error will be seen:****

```
[2018-07-03T15:08:37.447Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/70 on cam-iaas: Registering as an oauth client with ICP (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-03T15:08:37.733Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/70 on cam-iaas: Successfully registered as an oAuth Client with ICP. (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-03T15:08:37.734Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/70 on cam-iaas: Onboarding CAM Service into ICP (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-03T15:08:37.786Z] ERROR: orpheus-api-common/70 on cam-iaas: Failed to get IAM access token. Result: [object Object] (script=init-platform-security)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error suggests that one of the pre-req steps may not have been successful for "Generate a deployment ServiceID API Key".  Do you know if this step was done ok?  And if not, you can try uninstall and install it again by following [these steps](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_2.1.0.3/cam_prereq.html).

Generate a deployment ServiceID API Key:

```
export serviceIDName='service-deploy'
export serviceApiKeyName='service-deploy-api-key'
bx pr login -a https://localhost:8443 --skip-ssl-validation -u <admin_user>  -p <admin_password> -c id-mycluster-account
bx pr target -n services
bx pr iam service-id-create ${serviceIDName} -d 'Service ID for service-deploy'
bx pr iam service-policy-create ${serviceIDName} -r Administrator,ClusterAdministrator --service-name ''
bx pr iam service-api-key-create ${serviceApiKeyName} ${serviceIDName} -d 'Api key for service-deploy'
```

Use the API Key that you receive from the service-api-key-create command in deployApiKey value of Helm Chart install.

You can see that the API key was successfully used for registration with ICP in the iaas logs

```
[2018-07-11T06:28:50.258Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/110 on cam-iaas: Successfully created or retrieved an existing Service ID. (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-11T06:28:50.285Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/110 on cam-iaas: Successfully retrieved API Keys. (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-11T06:28:50.366Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/110 on cam-iaas: Successfully created or retrieved an existing API Key. (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-11T06:28:50.366Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/110 on cam-iaas: Successfully created or retrieved an existing CAM API Key. (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-11T06:28:50.453Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/110 on cam-iaas: Successfully retrieved IAM Access token. (script=init-platform-security)
[2018-07-11T06:28:50.454Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/110 on cam-iaas: Successfully generated an IAM Access token using CAM API Key. (script=init-platform-security)
```

The initial db errors are expected as iaas waits for the mongodb container to be ready, further down in the iaas log I do see the following which is good:

```
[2018-07-11T06:18:43.153Z]  INFO: orpheus-api-common/70 on cam-iaas: Successfully connected to db (script=connection-helper)
```